# android Volley how to post multiple parameters

Tags: android, android-volley

how to post multiple parameter android Volley
** post multiple array as like 101,102,103 params.put("sessionid", 101,102,103); //as like **
any other Way

```
    public void postCompanyArticle() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, config.postArticleTopBiz(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            list = parseResponse(response);
            adapter.setList(list);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            errorJson.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String msg = VolleyException.getErrorMessageFromVolleyError(error);
            errorJson.setText(msg);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("sessionid", 101,102,103);//as like
            params.put("EntID", "7");
            params.put("offset", String.valueOf(countView));
            params.put("limit", "10");
            params.put("LastLoginTime", "2016-02-01");
            return params;
        }

    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use for loops and it works fine.

```
@Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0; i < arraylist.size; i++)
        {
        params.put("sessionid["+i+"]",String.valueOf(arraylist.get(i)));
        }
        params.put("EntID", "7");
        params.put("offset", String.valueOf(countView));
        params.put("limit", "10");
        params.put("LastLoginTime", "2016-02-01");
        return params;
    }
```

arraylist is the list of your sessionid. This works for me.

Comment: Well In my case its not working since the data being posted in server changes `square brackets` `[]` to its html code i.e `%5B` and `%5D`

Comment: @PradeepKumarKushwaha you need to convert %5B and %5D on server side and its working fine.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Why its getting only the last index value?