# Using multiple values for the same param in a multipart's PartMap request with Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, hashmap, retrofit2, multipart

I want to send multiple values of the same param in a multipart query. Here is my code:

Interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("user")
Observable<Void> updateUser(@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> partMap, @Part MultipartBody.Part photo);
```

This request allow me to update a user with a new picture and some parameters. In the parameters I can specify the user's skills with a parameter named "skills[]". To specify the parameters that can vary in number I use a HashMap; however with a HashMap I cannot specify multiple parameters using the same name.

i.e. I cannot do:

```
for(Integer skill : skills) {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), skill.toString());
    map.put("skills[]", body);
}
```

Because the map will only accept one value of the same key.

How can I specify multiple values of a parameter. I have no problem doing it using Postman to test the request.

I tried to use a `HashMap<String, List<RequestBody>>` instead:

```
List<RequestBody> bodies = new ArrayList<>();
for(Integer skill : skills) {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), skill.toString());
    bodies.add(body);
}
map.put("skills[]", bodies);
```

but it seems that it's not supported. The query created contains null values for the request bodies:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="skills[]"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 16

[null,null,null]
```

Comment: check out this answer.The answer is about how to post multipale parameter in volley but I guess its working in your case.I do the same thing for Retrofit in my project and it works fine may be this helps for you. Here is [the refernce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239778/android-volley-how-to-post-multiple-parameters/35239922#35239922).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed thanks to [Andy Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5860777/andy-developer)

I still use the `HashMap<String, RequestBody>` but I provide different parameters names:

```
for(int i = 0; i < skills.size(); i++) {
    Integer skill = skills.get(i);
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), skill.toString());
    map.put("skills[" + i + "]", body);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this to create text RequestBody objects:

```
  RequestBody userPhone = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), phoneNumber);
  RequestBody userEmail = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), email);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I have no problem creating the RequestBody my issue is having multiple request bodies with the same name (in my case "skills[])

Comment: Ohh for that you can make a JSONArray and send it.  Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449803/android-adding-json-objects-into-an-array